# Raid Setup, 2 Hard drives - one shows in explorer

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bios, raid

I got a new pc delivered to me and I go to start up the PC using a raid configuration. I then go to `are you happy with these settings`and I select `yes`.

Later on, I then notice that one of the hard drives wasn't connected properly, so I connect it. I then boot up the computer and take a look in windows explorer to see if the second hard drive has shown up. **It didn't.**

I then try again, removing the hard drive's data cable and back in, rebooting, same issue. The hard drive doesn't appear in explorer.

What should I do? How can this problem be solved without losing any potential data on the hard drive?

Comment: Does this second drive have a filesystem on it? Explorer displays mounted filesystems, not disk drives. Also, you mention RAID. If this drive is in a RAID configuration with the other drive, I'd expect explorer to just display one filesystem.

Comment: Do you know what RAID level you are using 0-6?

Answer (score 0):

As stated on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID):

> RAID is a data storage virtualization technology that combines multiple disk drive components into a logical unit for the purposes of data redundancy or performance improvement.

If you have multiple drives on a RAID controller, I would think that they are supposed to appear as one, so what is happening should be happening.

Also, in explorer, what is the name of the drive that is there? Is it the name of the actual hard drive, or something relating to the RAID controller?

As Kenster pointed out, if your drives are not configured as RAID, the second drive will only show up if there is a file system on it, because explorer shows file systems, not the physical drives